# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^4)\sin(4^n)$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series

Is the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n^4)\sin(4^n) $$ convergent or divergent?

I tried expanding the sine functions and got no clue, and any test that I know of isn't helping me with this series. I even posted it on [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840334/the-series-sum-n-1-infty-sinn4-sin4n-converges-or-not) and someone there [advised](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840334/the-series-sum-n-1-infty-sinn4-sin4n-converges-or-not#comment7921471_3840334) me to seek help here.

Comment: why do you ask about this specific series?

Comment: While I fail to see why anyone would care about this particular series, I suspect this problem can be very hard: it is a question how small can the fractional parts $n^4 / \pi$ and $4^n / \pi$ get *simultaneously*. This mixes the additive and multiplicative structures, and so I suspect the answer is beyond the scope of tools available today. I added a top-level tag for [tag:real-analysis], as well as the [tag:ds.dynamical-systems] tag, someone more knowledgeable might give a better comment or answer.

Comment: Could you link to the MSE post?

Comment: Empirically, the general term $n\mapsto\sin(4^n)\sin(n^4)$ doesn't seem to converge to zero.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov I was given this series by a fellow student to solve and that's why it's in my interest.

Answer (score 9):

The terms of the series don't go to zero.

There is a uniquely ergodic dynamical system (with Lebesgue measure as the unique invariant measure) on the 4 dimensional torus and a function $f$ on the torus such that $f(T^n(0))=\sin(n^4)$. Since this dynamical system, there exists an $L$ such that for any $x$, one of $f(x),\ldots,f(T^{L-1}x)$ satisfies $f(x)\ge \frac 12$ (for example).

In particular for any $n$, at least one of $\sin(n^4),\ldots,\sin((n+L-1)^4)$ is at least $\frac 12$.

Now for any $n$, consider $a_n=\min(|\sin(4^n)|,\ldots,|\sin(4^{n+L-1})|)$.
If this is at least $1/4^{L+2}$, then one of the terms in the series between $n$ and $n+L$ is at least $1/(2\cdot 4^{L+2})$.

If it is less than $1/4^{L+2}$, find the first term $m$ after $n$ such that $|\sin(4^m)|>1/4^{L+2}$. In particular, since $|\sin(4x)|\le 4|\sin x|$, we see $|\sin(4^m)|\le 1/4^{L+1}$. Then $|\sin(4^{m+i})|\ge 1/4^{L+2}$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,L-1$. Amongst these terms, one of the $\sin(j^4)$ must exceed $\frac 12$, so that there is a term of size at least $1/(2\cdot 4^{L+2})$.

Comment: I think one can get by with just Weyl's inequality here, to prove a lower bound on $\sum_{k=0}^m \sin^2( (n+k)^4)$, instead of using ergodic theory.

Comment: @WillSawin: I guess I come from the other side of the tracks. For me, Weyl's inequality *is* ergodic theory!

Comment: @WillSawin to prove that the series diverges, or to prove the stronger fact that the term doesn't converge to 0?

Comment: @YCor: I believe Will is saying that the part of the argument where I used unique ergodicity to say that in any consecutive $L$ integers, one of the $|\sin(n^4)|$ is large is Weyl's inequality?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Well, instead of saying "instead of using ergodic theory" I could have said "without using the construction of Lebesgue measure (or indeed the definition of measure)" or "giving an effective bound".

Comment: Thanks. Precisely, does it provide an explicit positive lower bound on $\limsup \sin(n^4)\sin(4^n)$?

Comment: I think, both ergodic theory and Weyl inequalities are overkill. We have $\sum_{i=0}^4 (-1)^i\binom{i}4 (n+i)^4=24$, thus it is impossible that all $(n+i)^4$ for $i=0,1,2,3,4$ are almost divisible by $\pi$. This gives an explicit bound for limsup which @YCor ask about.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Cool!

Comment: @YCor Following Fedor Petrov, specifically since $24 \mod \pi = -1.132 \dots$, we must have one the integers $(n+i)^4 \mod \pi$ is at least $1.132\dots /16$, so  one of their sins is at least $\sin ( 1.132\dots  / 16 )$  which gives us a lower bound of $\sin (1.132 \dots/16) /4^{ 4+2} = .0000000675$

Comment: @Anthony quas what you've answered here is FAR beyond my current knowledge level. I don't understand any of this. If this problem is that hard then I don't understand why it is given to a BSc Mathematics 1st year student.

Comment: @Pritam: I don’t understand either why this would be assigned to a first year student, but this site is not intended for homework questions.

Comment: @anthony I understand... I thought this question was worth discussing that's why I uploaded it...it was far from homework, maybe he got it from somewhere because he's trying to strengthen his skills.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas but the proof after all is pretty elementary, why not to give it to first year student? I am resending this post to our professors who teach first year students.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Not clear how you deduce that $|\sin 4^{m+i} |\geq 1/4^{L+2}$. I would deduce a (worse) lower bound for $|\sin 4^{m-i}|$ but maybe I do not see. Are you using that $\lim sup |\sin 4^m|=1$?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: What I have in mind is that if $\theta$ is of the form $2\pi n+\epsilon$ with $\epsilon<1/4^{L+1}$, then $4^i\theta$ is of the form $2\pi m+\delta$ with $\delta<1/4$ for $i=1,\ldots,L$. The unique ergodicity argument (simplified by Fedor Petrov) ensures that this happens with bounded gaps.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you very much. Let me check whether how I have understood. You use that $\limsup |\sin 4^n| > 1/4^2$, select $n$ such that this is true and all the $m=n-L+1, \dots, n$ satisfy $|\sin 4^m| \geq 1/4^{L+2}$ (the rest is clear to me). Is this correct? By the way, is it true that $\limsup |\sin 4^n| =1$? I do not know even with $2^n$. Thank you.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I don't know whether $\limsup |\sin 4^n|=1$. While I don't see the proof the way you have described it, I think that what you are saying is correct (and is an interesting way to understand the proof).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas The point I do not understand in your proof is when you select  a large $n$ in such a way that $|\sin(4^n)| >1/4^{L+2}$. This requires that $\limsup |\sin (4^n)|=l>0$, which is true since the sequence does not converge to 0 becuse the derivative of $\sin(4x)$ at 0 is 4. However, to make everything quantitative one needs a lower bound on $l$ which should follow from duplication formulas (I did not check 1/16 but I will do). Having such an $n$ I find easier to go back, since $|\sin (4x)| \leq 4 |\sin x|$, as you indicates, instead of going forward.